# How to graphql after a certain date in contentful?

Tags: graphql, contentful, contentful-api

I'm using Contentful's GraphQL API. What I want to do is to query all the events that haven't past yet.

I tried using `lt`, but that doesn't seem to be working. I also found out that the date is a string, so what options do I have?

```
eventCollection(where: {eventEndDate: {lt: "2022-10-27T00:00:00.000-06:00"}}){
    items {
      slug
      eventEndDate
    }
  }
```

A normal query (without the where condition) gives you:

```
"eventCollection": {
      "items": [
        {
          "slug": "black-friday",
          "eventEndDate": "2022-11-27T12:00:00.000-07:00"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have an `eventEndDate_gte` filter available. On every field, there will be type dependent filter available. It's best to use [GraphiQL](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/graphql/#/reference/exploring-the-schema-with-graphiql) or [the GraphQL Playground](https://www.contentful.com/marketplace/app/graphql-playground/) to discover available filter options.

The following filter works fine for my space.

```
query {
  tilPostCollection(where: {date_gte: "2022-09-05T00:00:00.000+02:00"}) {
    items {
      title
      date
    }
  }
}
```